I am getting TLS error while trying to connet to RabbitMQ
I want to set up certificate-based authentication with a RabbitMQ server and a .Net client.
The TLS itself seems to be working, as connecting with openssl works:

Connecting to ::1
CONNECTED(00000198)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=1 CN=MyCA
verify error:num=19:self-signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=1 CN=MyCA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN=localhost
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN=localhost
   i:CN=MyCA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jul  3 12:46:46 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Jul  2 12:46:46 2029 GMT
 1 s:CN=MyCA
   i:CN=MyCA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jul  3 10:56:20 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Jul  1 10:56:20 2034 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDFTCCAf2gAwIBAgIUXo2XnoUU32ukwDybe7FfdfFe30swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
.............
+Y0AEuM1niON33+H47MxIlDIYXjcjCM+LA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN=localhost
issuer=CN=MyCA
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
CN=MyCA
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed448:Ed25519
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed448:Ed25519
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2213 bytes and written 1503 bytes
Verification error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 19 (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
closed


On the server-side I get this, which is expectable as the tool does not send anything, just connects:

2024-07-03 14:53:44 2024-07-03 12:53:44.372034+00:00 [info] <0.966.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.966.0> (172.31.0.1:46438 -> 172.31.0.2:5671)
2024-07-03 14:53:44 2024-07-03 12:53:44.372459+00:00 [error] <0.966.0> closing AMQP connection <0.966.0> (172.31.0.1:46438 -> 172.31.0.2:5671):
2024-07-03 14:53:44 2024-07-03 12:53:44.372459+00:00 [error] <0.966.0> {handshake_timeout,handshake}


I can't get the RabbitMQ.Client library to connect:
var factory = new ConnectionFactory 
    { 
        HostName = "localhost",
        Port = 5671,
        VirtualHost = "generic",
        AuthMechanisms = [ new ExternalMechanismFactory() ],
        Ssl = new SslOption
        {
            Enabled = true,
            ServerName = "localhost",
            AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors,
            CertPath = @"D:\...\certs\generic_user_certificate.pfx",
        }
};
using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

I get following excpetion: BrokerUnreachableException > None of the specified endpoints were reachable > Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'InsuffientSecurity'
On the server side it looks like this:

2024-07-03 14:54:08 2024-07-03 12:54:08.171263+00:00 [notice] <0.977.0> TLS server: In state hello at tls_handshake.erl:354 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Insufficient Security
2024-07-03 14:54:08 2024-07-03 12:54:08.171263+00:00 [notice] <0.977.0>  - no_suitable_ciphers


If I restrict the version:
new SslOption
{
 Version = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls13,...
}

I get following inner exception message: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm. bubbling up from System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions, Boolean newCredentialsRequested), and the server does not diplay anything. If `System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12˙is used, I get the error from before. Meaning that it first tries 1.3 then falls back to 1.2 bot neither succeess.
The openssl command with -tls1_2 yields the same error on the server and following output:

Connecting to ::1
CONNECTED(00000194)
14050000:error:0A00042F:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert insufficient security:../openssl-3.2.1/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:865:SSL alert number 71
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 194 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1720012876
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---


NMAP result:

nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 5671 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-07-03 16:25 Central Europe Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: kubernetes.docker.internal

PORT     STATE SERVICE
5671/tcp open  amqps
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.3:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A


Environment:

RabbitMQ 3.13.3 with Erlang 26.2.5.1, with rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl enabled from rabbitmq:3-management-alpine docker image
client: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.19045 Build 19045
.NET SDK. 8.0.300
As far as I can tell, I should have all on the client:



[Update]
I have missed it, but @SteffenUllrich spotted it: TLS 1.3 client is missing from the image altogether. Ok. I have enabled it in the registry. And restarted the PC.

But the issue is still there. I have Windows 10 build 19045, which is 22H2, that supports TLSv1.3 according to this page. Interestingly, IIS Crypto 3.3 still does not show it.
[Update 2024.07.09]
Status: Win10 does NOT support TLSv1.3. But I can't get RabbitMQ docker image to support v1.2, even if it should out of the box.
I have prepared a repository: https://github.com/zorgoz/rabbitmq-tsl-issue
It has the exact same setup, with a minimal test code.

RabbitMQ 3.13.4
NMAP to "extract" supported TLS versions and ciphers
test code

RabbitMQ startup

Test code output:

Related RabbitMQ log (proving certs are correct, TLS is working):

NMAP output for RabbitMQ dockered server:

No TLSv1.2 at all....
Obviously, because of this, the Windows 10 client can't connect.
Just for reference, same NMAP call just using microsoft's server as target:


The question is probably what ciphers RabbitMQ accepts. The software is not going to lie to you, there apparently is not a single cipher that the client (.NET in this case) presents which the server accepts. The documentation shows how to list accepted ciphers and also how to configure them : https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/ssl#cipher-suites

It is clear from what you write that the client does not support TLS 1.3 but that the server requires TLS 1.3. How to fix this problem depends on what end you can control regarding TLS version - which is not clear.

@SteffenUllrich Yes, you must be right. I looked at the chippers only. Now I have checked the registry, and there is indeed no 1.3... I will try to enable it.

@SteffenUllrich. See update. Although many articles are saying that Win10 has TLS1.3 support. It seems that even if it was introduced, it seems not to be available. The new question is: how can I restrict the server to only v1.2?

@ZorgoZ: You don't need to restrict the server to TLS 1.2 but you need to allow TLS 1.2, which can coexist with TLS 1.3. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/ssl#tls-versions for the relevant configurations in RabbitMQ

@SteffenUllrich I already tried that. It does not change what nmap spits out. As if there is no 1.2 support at all. If enable only 1.2 nothing is returned. If I enable both, only 1.3 is returned. I have tested with another random server and there I got both.

@ZorgoZ: " I have tested with another random server and there I got both." - what do you mean with "random server" - same docker image, same configuration?

@SteffenUllrich the "random server" was microsoft.com on port 443 just to see if NMAP reports TSL support for both versions (nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 microsoft.com). And it does. microsoft.com reported both, my rabbitmq reported only 1.3 regardless of the configuration. According to others, when nothing is specified both v1.2 and v1.3 should be supported. Well, not for this docker image.
